# Matplotlib: draw lines with width given in data coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to draw lines with widths in data units. For example, in the following code snippet, I would want the horizontal part of the line of width 80 to always extend from the y=-40 to the y=+40 mark, and stay that way even if the limits of the coordinate system change. Is there a way to achieve this with Line2D objects in matplotlib? Any other way to get a similar effect?

```
from pylab import figure, gca, Line2D

figure()
ax = gca()
ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
ax.set_ylim(-75, 75)

ax.add_line(Line2D([-50, 0, 50], [-50, 0, 0], linewidth=80))

ax.grid()
```

[image: line width in screen coordinates]

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean that if the window expands you want the blue line to *still* span from about `y=-25` to `y=25` in the picture you've posted?

Comment: @unutbu The width is set to 80, I think the OP wants it to be from -40 to 40 always. Your answer seems to be what the OP needs.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19397279/1681480) is a way to do it with lines of any angle, not just padding vertically...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
ax.set_ylim(-75, 75)
x = [-50, 0, 50]
y = np.array([-50, 0, 0])

ax.fill_between(x,y-30,y+30)

ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

but unlike the line generated by

```
ax.add_line(Line2D([-50, 0, 50], [-50, 0, 0], linewidth=80))
```

the vertical thickness of the line will always be constant in data coordinates.

See also [link to documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between).

Comment: +1. The call can be simplified to `ax.fill_between([-50, 50], -25, 25)` in this case, byw.

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't work for lines that aren't exactly horizontal, right? I should have been more specific that I want to do this for arbitrary lines -- I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Actually, `fill_between` works [fine with curves](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

Comment: Oh, brilliant! I had no idea. That does achieve exactly what I want.

Comment: The thickness of the line is not constant ... the height of it is.  These are the same for horizontal lines, but very steep sections will be much skinnier.

Answer (score 2):

In order to draw a line with the linewidth in data units, you may want to have a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/4124317)**.

It uses a class `data_linewidth_plot` which closely resembles the `plt.plot()` command's signature.

```
l = data_linewidth_plot( x, y, ax=ax, label='some line', linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.4)
```

The linewidth argument is interpreted in (y-)data units.