# Scale matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.scatter markersize by x-scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I would like to scale the `markersize` of `matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.scatter` plot based on the number of points on the x/y-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vmin = 1
vmax = 11

x = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)
y = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for v in np.arange(vmin, vmax):
    ax.axvline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axvline(v + 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v + 0.5)

ax.set_xlim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)
ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

`ax` is always using an equal aspect ratio and both axes have the same `lim` values.

Currently, running the above generates the following plot ...
[image]

...and changing the value of `vmax = 41`
[image]

The `markersize` in both plots is left to the default, i.e. `markersize=6`.

My question is, how could I compute the `markersize` value so the `marker`s touch the edges of each cell? (Each cell has a maximum of one data point.)

Comment: Good question, but should be `vmax = 11` for plot provided. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Using Circles

An easy option is to replace the scatter by a `PatchCollection` consisting of `Circles` of radius 0.5.

```
circles = [plt.Circle((xi,yi), radius=0.5, linewidth=0) for xi,yi in zip(x,y)]
c = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(circles)
ax.add_collection(c)
```

[image]

#### Using scatter with markers of size in data units

The alternative, if a scatter plot is desired, would be to update the markersize to be in data units.

The easy solution here would be to first draw the figure once, then take the axes size and calculate the markersize in points from it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vmin = 1
vmax = 11

x = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)
y = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=141)
for v in np.arange(vmin, vmax):
    ax.axvline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axvline(v + 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v + 0.5)

ax.set_xlim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)

ax.set_aspect(1)
fig.canvas.draw()
s = ((ax.get_window_extent().width  / (vmax-vmin+1.) * 72./fig.dpi) ** 2)

ax.scatter(x, y, s = s, linewidth=0)

plt.show()
```

For some background on how markersize of scatters is used, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403507/4124317). The drawback of the above solution is that is fixes the marker size to the size and state of the plot. In case the axes limits would change or the plot is zoomed, the scatter plot would again have the wrong sizing.

Hence the following solution would be more generic.
This is a little involved and would work similarly as [Plotting a line with width in data units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394505/matplotlib-expand-the-line-with-specified-width-in-data-unit).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vmin = 1
vmax = 32

x = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)
y = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for v in np.arange(vmin, vmax):
    ax.axvline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axvline(v + 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v - 0.5)
    ax.axhline(v + 0.5)

ax.set_xlim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(vmin - 0.5, vmax + 0.5)

class scatter():
    def __init__(self,x,y,ax,size=1,**kwargs):
        self.n = len(x)
        self.ax = ax
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.size_data=size
        self.size = size
        self.sc = ax.scatter(x,y,s=self.size,**kwargs)
        self._resize()
        self.cid = ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self._resize)

    def _resize(self,event=None):
        ppd=72./self.ax.figure.dpi
        trans = self.ax.transData.transform
        s =  ((trans((1,self.size_data))-trans((0,0)))*ppd)[1]
        if s != self.size:
            self.sc.set_sizes(s**2*np.ones(self.n))
            self.size = s
            self._redraw_later()
    
    def _redraw_later(self):
        self.timer = self.ax.figure.canvas.new_timer(interval=10)
        self.timer.single_shot = True
        self.timer.add_callback(lambda : self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle())
        self.timer.start()


sc = scatter(x,y,ax, linewidth=0)

ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.show()
```

(I updated the code to use a timer to redraw the canvas, due to [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10334))

Comment: Excellent answer! I really like the idea of converting to data units.

Comment: @tdube There is no need to delete your answer. You could have just updated it with the information from the comments. But since you did delete it I included that part in my answer above, because it might indeed be useful for other people as well.

Comment: Great answer! Exactly what I wanted to do. I prefer the simple approach since it is enough for what I need but thanks for explaining the data units approach too.

Comment: Please take a look at my question at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543182/specifying-matplotlib-scatter-size-in-plot-units I have tried to implement your class but it seems that it is not plotting in true data units. Do you mind taking a look ? Thanks!