# Plotting a Heatmap with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

I want to generate a heatmap using Python.
The map should be like this:

[image]
I have a numpy array with dimension (n,n) and each "cell" contains a certain value. The higher higher that value is, the bigger a pink square should be.
How can I plot this kind of chart using matplotlib? Are there other libraries that I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean 'Heatmap'?

Comment: `Heatmap` was my first thought, too, but it would mean color encoded data... This is a scatter plot with squared markers, isn't it?

Comment: You can make use of filled `patches.Rectangle`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image) is a link on how to use them. You can map your values to the size of the square and use them as the length of the edges of the rectangle

Comment: Sometimes I find it referred as "hit-map" and sometimes as "heat-map", anyway the heat-map should be slightly different based on what I have found, indeed it doesn't change the "dimension" of the pink squares but only their colour if I am right (anyway I have already implemented a simple heatmap in Python, but I don't know how to implement this other one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
n = 8
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.arange(n)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.random.randint(0, 800, (len(x), len(y)))
plt.figure()
plt.axes(aspect='equal')
plt.scatter(X+.5, Y+.5, Z, 'pink', marker='s')
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(0, n)
plt.ylim(0, n)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=0, length=0)
```

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174228/4124317) can be of interest as I suppose the size of the scatter markers needs to be normalized, such that no square is bigger than the containing cell.

Comment: Indeed, the non-dynamical marker size of scatter might be a drawback here, so thanks for the useful link.

Comment: This is very useful but there is a problem with larger charts, anyway it is possible to easily manage those cases normalizing the Z dimensions.