# Changing x, y axis changes Matplotlib scatter bubbles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a labelled bubble plot. I have specified the location of each bubble at `x,y` in a df. My issue is that the plot cuts off the edges of the bubbles:

[image]

I thought I could correct this by changing the `x` and `y` axis limits, however this also moves the bubbles:

[image]

I have looked for solutions and tried adding `ax.margins(2, 2)` but this also does not work:

[image]

I'm really interested to know why this happens? And how to fix it please? Many thanks in advance. Here is my code, including what I've tried:

````
x = [-0.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 4.3, 0, 2.9]
y = [0.94, 1.04, 1.5, 0.7, 1.3, 1.55, 1]
size = [5850, 2600, 6500, 1300, 4550, 7150, 1950]
label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

df = pd.DataFrame({
'x': x,
'y': y,
's': size,
'label': label
})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='w')

#plt.xlim(-2,7)
#plt.ylim(0.4,2)

#ax.margins(2, 2) 

for key, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.scatter(row['x'], row['y'], s=row['s']*5, alpha=.5)
    ax.annotate(row['label'], xy=(row['x'], row['y']))```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scale matplotlib.pyplot.Axes.scatter markersize by x-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172928/scale-matplotlib-pyplot-axes-scatter-markersize-by-x-scale)

Comment: See also this interesting thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14827650/8881141

Comment: Yes! Both very helpful indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that marker size `s` is in image points**2, not in coordinated units:

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

You can verify it, open the console and write:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.scatter([0], [0], s=10)
# Check, how it looks now
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
# Check that it looks the same
```

`scatter` is not right tool for this job. Use `Ellipse`, here there is some inspiration:

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/shapes_and_collections/ellipse_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-ellipse-demo-py