# True Python scatter function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I am writing this to have a reference post when it comes to plotting circles with a scatter plot but the user wants to provide a real radius for the scattered circles instead of an abstract size.

I have been looking around and there are other posts that explain the theory of it, but have not come accross a ready-to-use function. I have tried myself and hope that I am close to finding the solution.

This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def true_scatter(x, y, r, ax, **kwargs):
    # Should work for an equal aspect axis
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    
    # Access the DPI and figure size
    dpi = ax.figure.dpi
    fig_width_inch, _ = ax.figure.get_size_inches()

    # Calculate plot size in data units
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    plot_width_data_units = xlim[1] - xlim[0]

    # Calculate the scale factor: pixels per data unit
    plot_width_pixels = fig_width_inch * dpi
    scale = plot_width_pixels / plot_width_data_units

    # Convert radius to pixels, then area to points squared
    radius_pixels = r * scale
    area_pixels_squared = np.pi * (radius_pixels ** 2)
    area_points_squared = area_pixels_squared * (72 / dpi) ** 2

    # Scatter plot with converted area
    scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=area_points_squared, **kwargs)
    return scatter

# Example with single scatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
scatter = true_scatter(0, 0, 1, ax)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[Wrong single scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f7sW.png)

Unfortunately, it is not quite the answer. I get a circle of radius ~1.55 instead of 1.
Would anyone be able to spot what is wrong with my approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear whether you want `r` to be the radius or the diameter of the circle.  The code below supposes it is the radius (just leave out the `* 2` if you want the diameter.

For a discussion about how the dot size is measured, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size).

The code below converts the radius in data units to pixels, and then to "points". Three different sizes are tested.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def true_scatter(x, y, r, ax, **kwargs):
    # the radius is given in data coordinates in the x direction
    # Should work for an equal aspect axis
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    # measure the data coordinates in pixels
    radius_in_pixels, _ = ax.transData.transform((r, 0)) - ax.transData.transform((0, 0))
    # one "point" is 1/72 of an inch
    radius_in_points = radius_in_pixels * 72.0 / ax.figure.dpi
    # the scatter plot size is set in square point units
    area_points_squared = (radius_in_points * 2) ** 2

    # Scatter plot with converted area
    scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=area_points_squared, **kwargs)
    return scatter

# Example with three scatter dots with different radii
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
scatter = true_scatter(0, 0, 1.5, ax)
scatter = true_scatter(0, 0, 1, ax)
scatter = true_scatter(0, 0, 0.5, ax)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with radius in data units]

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174228/12131013), I was able to update your function to work correctly. Note the following changes:

- You should draw the axes before getting dimensions because the values haven't been initialized yet (I'm not sure if that explanation is entirely correct, but at least know that before drawing the values aren't what they will be after the figure is drawn).
- You should use the axes width rather than the figure width since you're drawing on the axes.
- The area for matplotlib should not include pi, so it should just be the scaled-r squared.
- The edge color will make the marker slightly bigger.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

def true_scatter(x, y, r, ax, **kwargs):
    # Should work for an equal aspect axis
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    fig = ax.figure
    fig.canvas.draw()   # need to draw before getting the dimensions
    
    # Access the DPI and axes size
    dpi = fig.dpi
    ax_width = ax.get_window_extent().width

    # Calculate plot size in data units
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    plot_width_data_units = xlim[1] - xlim[0]

    # Calculate the scale factor: pixels per data unit
    # 72/dpi because that is the conversion factor from matplotlib
    scale = ax_width/plot_width_data_units*(72/dpi)

    # Convert radius to pixels, then area to points squared
    radius_pixels = r*scale
    s = radius_pixels**2
    
    # the edge color makes the point look slightly larger than it is
    kwargs["edgecolor"] = kwargs.get("edgecolor", "none")

    # Scatter plot with converted area
    scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=s, **kwargs)
    return scatter

# Example with single scatter
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
scatter = true_scatter(0, 0, 1, ax)
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As mentioned in the linked answer, resizing the figure or zooming in will screw up your scaling.

Comment: I suspect " +1 for some reason" isn't working well.  Did you test the code with different xlims? Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size) suggests that no multiplication with `pi` should be involved.  After some testing, I think this version of the code works because `0.5 * np.pi * 5 / 4` is close to `2`.

Comment: Working with `ax.get_window_extent()` seems a bit more intuitive than my approach.  Probably you can change your code to `plot_width_data_units = xlim[1] - xlim[0]`, rename `radius_pixels` to `radius_in_points` and set `s = radius_in_points ** 2` (or `s = (2*radius_in_points) ** 2`, depending on the interpretation of `r`).

Comment: @JohanC I think you're right. I've made the change.