# `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` with the linewidth given in data units (not points)

Tags: python, matplotlib

**I would like to create a `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` like patch, with the linewidth given in data units (not points).**

I am aware that for patches with a regular shape, one can mimic such an object by drawing two patches of different sizes on top of each other.
However, this approach becomes a lot more computationally involved for arbitrary shapes (need to compute a parallel line for an arbitrary shape).
Furthermore, I would like to retain the `PathPath` object methods, so ultimately I am looking for a class derived from `PathPatch` or `Patch`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch, Rectangle

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

origin = (0, 0)
width = 1
height = 2
lw = 0.25

outer = Rectangle((origin[0],    origin[1]),    width,      height,      facecolor='darkblue',  zorder=1)
inner = Rectangle((origin[0]+lw, origin[1]+lw), width-2*lw, height-2*lw, facecolor='lightblue', zorder=2)

ax1.add_patch(outer)
ax1.add_patch(inner)
ax1.axis([-0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 2.5])
ax1.set_title('Desired')

path = outer.get_path().transformed(outer.get_patch_transform())
pathpatch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='lightblue', edgecolor='darkblue', linewidth=lw)
ax2.add_patch(pathpatch)
ax2.set_title('Actual')

plt.show()
```

[image]

There is a [different SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/2912349) that derives from `Line2D` to create a line with widths in data units.

```
class LineDataUnits(Line2D):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/2912349
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _lw_data = kwargs.pop("linewidth", 1)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._lw_data = _lw_data

    def _get_lw(self):
        if self.axes is not None:
            ppd = 72./self.axes.figure.dpi
            trans = self.axes.transData.transform
            return ((trans((1, self._lw_data))-trans((0, 0)))*ppd)[1]
        else:
            return 1

    def _set_lw(self, lw):
        self._lw_data = lw

    _linewidth = property(_get_lw, _set_lw)
```

I don't quite understand how this implementation works (for example, no methods of `Line2D` seem to be overwritten)
Nevertheless, I have tried copying this approach (`class LineDataUnits(Line2D)` -> `class PathPatchDataUnits(PathPatch)`), but -- unsurprisingly -- cannot get it to work (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_figure'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I made it work and got some insights on the way.
First of all, here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch, Rectangle

# The class from the solution you found, I just changed inheritance 
class PatchDataUnits(PathPatch):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42972469/2912349
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _lw_data = kwargs.pop("linewidth", 1)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._lw_data = _lw_data

    def _get_lw(self):
        if self.axes is not None:
            ppd = 72./self.axes.figure.dpi
            trans = self.axes.transData.transform
            # the line mentioned below
            return ((trans((self._lw_data, self._lw_data))-trans((0, 0)))*ppd)[1]
        else:
            return 1

    def _set_lw(self, lw):
        self._lw_data = lw

    _linewidth = property(_get_lw, _set_lw)

# Your code example
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

origin = (0, 0)
width = 1
height = 2
lw = 0.25

outer = Rectangle((origin[0],    origin[1]),    width,      height,      facecolor='darkblue',  zorder=1)
inner = Rectangle((origin[0]+lw, origin[1]+lw), width-2*lw, height-2*lw, facecolor='lightblue', zorder=2)

ax1.add_patch(outer)
ax1.add_patch(inner)
ax1.axis([-0.5, 1.5, -0.5, 2.5])
ax1.set_title('Desired')

# change lw because it overlaps some of the fig
mlw = lw /2 
# create new patch with the adusted size
mid = Rectangle((origin[0]+mlw, origin[1]+mlw), width-2*mlw, height-2*mlw, facecolor='lightblue',  zorder=1)
path = mid.get_path().transformed(mid.get_patch_transform())
# Use the data unit class to create the path patch with the original lw
pathpatch = PatchDataUnits(path, facecolor='lightblue', edgecolor='darkblue', linewidth=lw)
ax2.add_patch(pathpatch)
ax2.set_title('Actual')

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: The results I got on my machine]

Now for my thoughts:

The `axes.transData` transform really is a composition of two transforms, one for x-coordinates, the other for y-coordinates.
However, a linewidth is a single scalar, therefor we need to make a choice which of the two transforms we will use.
In my solution, I use the y-transform; however, by changing the line below the comment to index [0], you can select to use the x-transform.
If the aspect of the axis is equal (i.e. a horizontal line of length 1 in data units has the same length in display units as a vertical line of length 1 in data units),
this is not an issue. However, if the aspect is not equal, this may yield to unexpected behaviour as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The aspect of an axis can be forced to be equal using the command `ax.set_aspect('equal')`.

Comment: Hi @yotam, thank you for your fantastic work, and thank you for all the time you put in. I did see your other attempts yesterday but didn't have time to respond.

Comment: The surprising behaviour that you discuss is not an issue for my use case. Also it can be easily prevented by setting the axis aspect to be equal (`ax.set_aspect('equal')`).

Comment: I suggested some edits to your post; however, these are really just suggestions, feel free to reject them.

Comment: HI @PaulBrodersen, it's no problem after some time it became a personal challenge to make it work. Also thanks for your edit I like your phrasing better than my original :)